# WP-Admin redirects to old URL (after editing config.php)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get a client's WordPress site copied over to my company's server to use as a development site. I've ran into an issue when trying to log into the site's administrator panel; it redirects us to the existing site's URL instead (ending up as [OLD SITE]/[NEW URL]/wp-admin). Additionally, trying to go to any page other than the homepage gets a 404.

I've tried editing the wp-config and defining the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL there, with no success. In a previous attempt we used a backup tool that was meant to replace references to the old URL with the new URL, and on another we ran queries and checked through wp-options in the database to be sure that we caught all of the old references. Still redirects to the old site.

We've tried restoring from two backups, Akeeba and BackUpWordPress. Our current attempt is a copy we've downloaded directly and then uploaded (with an imported SQL backup).

Another odd thing I've noted is that changing one of the URLs in the database causes more issues. Mainly, if I update the URL of 'wordpress-https_ssl_host' in the wp-options table, the theme breaks. Not sure where to go with this from here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always succesfully using the following script : search & replace:
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

in order to update a wordpress site url.
Just copy the provided code in a directory under your site, then launch the provided index.php in a browser: the database infos should be automatically determined. Then specify the old and new urls and click on "Run" !
Don't forget to remove the created directory afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

We found the problem; as it turns out it was nothing to do with anything from the default WordPress files. The client was using an extension called WordPress HTTPS, and apparently that was causing a conflict somewhere. We renamed the extension's folder to disable it and everything ran fine. I imagine it was overriding what we were setting in wp-config.

Answer (score -1):

For solving this issue you have to change `siteurl` in database `wp_options` table

`option_name` = `siteurl` where 
`option_value` = `YOUR OLD SITE URL`

change your old site url and update it with your local developement site URL

Hope this will help you..